# C# selenium: Selecting the value from the list box

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm working on writing a selenium script, where i need to select the list box which gets populated once i enter the text in the textbox. But i'm not able to the select the listbox item with the below peice of code,

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("hiringManager")).SendKeys(ExcelLibrary.ReadData(1, "HiringManager"));
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        SelectElement selectHiringManager = new SelectElement(webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("hiringManagerIds")));
        selectHiringManager.SelectByText(ExcelLibrary.ReadData(1, "HiringManager"));
```

Please let me know how do i select the listbox item

[image]

Comment: You are using `ExcelLibrary.ReadData(1,"HiringManager"));` to both input text in textbox and select item from list box. What is the value of `ExcelLibrary.ReadData(1, "HiringManager"));`? If it is `S` then item can not be selected coz there is no item in list box with text `S`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue with the below code,

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("hiringManager")).SendKeys(ExcelLibrary.ReadData(1, "HiringManager"));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select[name=hiringManagerIds] option:nth-child(1)")).Click();
```